Libcurl multi: removing completed transfer before checking for messages, will the message be still in the queue?
I have a situation where, using the multi-interface, I have a set of running transfers, and at some point I would like to stop one of them, even if I'm not sure if the transfer has already completed or not (e.g., I don't care at this point if that particular transfer completed or not). I would like to know what exactly happens with the message queue (the one you query with curl_multi_info_read) when the transfer is stopped, or if I remove the easy handler after removing it, but before checking for messages.
Imagine the following situation:
CURL* h = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(blablabla);
// more setopts, url, etc

curl_multi_add_handle(my_curlm, h);

int running_transfers;
curl_multi_perform(my_curlm, &running_transfers);

// At some point in the future:
curl_multi_remove_handle(my_curlm, h);

I have two doubts at this point:

If the transfer was not done yet, will the message queue be populated with a new message for that handler indicating that it's finished? If that's the case, is there any result code that I can check to know that the transfer ended because it was explicitely stopped? NOTE: One of the CURL error codes is CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK, but I don't know if stopping the transfer by removing it from the multi handler is covered by this error code.
If the transfer was already done and there's a new message inside the queue, or if the transfer was not done yet but stopping it inserted a new message in the queue (the above scenario), and I then remove the easy handler with curl_easy_cleanup, will the message dissapear from the queue, or do I need to keep the easy handler alive UNTIL I checked all the messages in the queue?

My prefered semantics here are that, regardless of whether the transfer is done or not done yet, or whether there's pending messages on the queue referred to it or not, if I remove the easy handler with curl_easy_cleanup (after removing it from the multi handler), any message refered to that easy handler dissappears.
